# Finding ads specific to a location from Google AdMobs

Tags: location, admob

How to find ads by location in an android app using Google AdMobs?
Is there a way to query the ads by supplying zip code/gps data to Google AdMobs?
How does the location based targeting of ads work in google admobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
adRequest.setLocation(location);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

There are many ways to get the Location, but if you are serving ads based upon the user's current location then you will want to use the LocationManager.